# PHP foreach with counter and IF statement

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach, counter

I am trying to use a FOREACH loop in PHP to output different messages depending on the position of the value in the array.  My code is below:

```
$qtyValidFiles = count($validFiles);
$tick = 0;
                 foreach($validFiles AS $validItem)
                {
                    if($tick = 0)
                    {
                    echo"'#$validItem,";
                    }
                    elseif($tick < $qtyValidFiles -1 && $tick != 0)
                    {
                    echo"#$validItem,";
                    }
                    elseif($tick = $qtyValidFiles -1)
                    {
                    echo"#$validItem'";
                    }
                }; $tick++;
```

In this instance, `$qtyValidFiles` has 4 values.

The code above returns:

```
#Games'#Movies'#Music'#TV'
```

which suggests to me that `$tick` is always being seen as value `3`.

Comment: use $tick == 0 in your if statement

Comment: Comparison operator is `==`.

Comment: You're incrementing `$tick` outside the loop.

Comment: Haha, and I just saw what you're trying to do.  See my edit `implode()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$validFiles` is an indexed array, you can do:

```
foreach ($validFiles as $tick => $validItem)
```

instead of incrementing `$tick` yourself.

Your entire loop is unnecessary, though. You can do:

```
echo "'" . implode(",", array_map(function($x) { return "#$x"; }, $validFiles)) . "'";
```

This should be better than your code because you don't do the right thing if the array has exactly 1 item; you'll print the beginning quote and a comma, but I think you really want the one element surrounded by quotes.

Answer (score 0):

`$tick` is always `0` because the `$tick++;` is outside of the loop.  Move it up a line.

Also as `Rahul Kumar` states, use == as the comparison operator.

Or just do this, no loop needed:

```
echo '#' . implode(',#', $validFiles);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the simpler and correct equivalent to your code would be this:

```
$qtyValidFiles = count($validFiles);
$str = '';
foreach($validFiles AS $validItem) {
   $str .= "#$validItem,";
}
if (!empty($str)) {
   echo "'" . substr($str, 0, -1) . "'"; //removes the last ","
}
```